# Current Mirror (or other solution) for driving individual LED channels of different specifications

Tags: bjt

I have recently encountered an issue with an extremely low power system with variable Vcc (due to power harvesting) I am developing that requires LED functionality. Traditionally, these LEDs (up to 4) are driven straight from I/O pins of an ATTiny84 and this works fine when the LEDs are matched and have similar forward voltage characteristics.

The problem occurs when different LED(s) are used in other channels. Now there is behavior where they dominate each other in different situations (e.g. in low Vcc situation, the LED that has a lower forward voltage turns on only, however when the source voltage is higher, the other LED begins to overtake the first in terms of brightness). This makes it very difficult to find simple resistor values that fit each LED, especially considering variable LED characteristics even within the same batch.

I did some research and attempted to design a current mirror circuit to address this (below), and simulation results were promising in LTSpice, though I know this is in very ideal circumstances. The accuracy of the actual mirroring is not too important as long as it is reasonably close so that certain LEDs are not dominating others. The disconnected GNDs on the bottom represent I/O input that would either ground the individual channel or disconnect it by changing the I/O direction register. I notice that when I disconnect one or more channels, the overall mirrored current changes for the remaining channels.

[image: Proposed current mirror circuit for LED driving]

Are there any other techniques that could be used? Any tips on the circuit? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Edit: - I forgot to mention, but I am limited to very small (0402 or 0201, or some comparable magnitude of size) components in my design unfortunately. Some ICs will be off the table or very difficult to source

Comment: Welcome! How is current limited to each LED?

Comment: What's the current capability of that 3.3 V supply? Is it enough to drive all the current you're demanding?

Comment: Why do you think the subjective brightness of the colors will match just because the LED currents are the same?

Comment: tomhebe, Talk more about how all this will be used. Is this to be used in a multiplexing situation? If so, details are needed before I can ask you to think about some cases to worry over. And just as a side note from experience, I at least set up individual current systems for each color when this would be RGB usage. So I'd like to know if you are just slapping down different colors for some random reason or if you plan an RGB color system of any kind. And there's much more that's needed. In the meantime, ask yourself what happens when one LED there is missing, for example. What do you see?

Comment: @winny That is the issue I am having. Using I/O and a resistor to drive the LEDs causes an imbalance in the current due to the non-linear behavior. I am trying to get a very rough mirroring of current between LEDs. It does not have to be close to accurate as you would have on an IC, however, just enough to confine each LED to *roughly* the same forward current.

Comment: @Hearth It is tough to say due to the power being harvested wirelessly. The allowable current/voltage is different based on the harvesting conditions, however it is rectified and regulated. I am able to easily drive 4 of the same type of LED, the issue occurs when mixing them, which I can only assume is due to different forward voltage characteristics.

Comment: @Jens The optical performance of each of these LEDs have characterized individually at different operating conditions. The performance is not my current chief concern as much as establishing equal drive conditions for each

Comment: @periblepsis Thanks for the questions. I can't be too specific, however, the purpose is to simply enable the LEDs to flash/blink at different frequencies and Duty Cycles. The actual operation of the device in terms of its functionality has already been implemented and proven. I am simply trying to solve the problem I have been having where non-linear LED behavior causes the LEDs to overdraw current from each other (i.e. when both LEDs are on at the same time, say at a 100% Duty Cycle, one will be clearly brighter than the other until Vcc is high enough, at which point the other LED is brighter

Comment: My question was rhetorical. You must limit the current somehow. As your schematic is drawn, it does not but it’s rather up to a dice roll on hfe on each transistor.

Comment: @tomhebe I want you to consider the case where one of the LEDs is broken (doesn't work or isn't present.) What do you expect to see in this case? Think about it...

Answer (score 0):

This may work well in simulation, but not quite as well in practice. Different NPNs will have different VBE for a given current and so their currents may not match.

The switch that grounds the emitters should also have a 'dummy' on on Q1 (always on) to create the same offset there.

Depending on your wiring, is it possible that your real circuit is oscillating (if brightness changes when you *touch* a wire, then oscillation is likely the culprit). You may use a capacitor (0.1 - 1 uF ?) from Q1 collector to GND.

Answer (score 0):

There's always the good old [LM334](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm334.pdf) current regulator. It's no bigger than a single transistor, and requires only one additional resistor to set current. You could duplicate this for each LED:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frhFmf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LM334 will drop at least 1V. If, after the LED has removed its own \$V_F\$ from the supply potential difference, less than 1V remains for the LM334, then current regulation will fail, so this solution may be unsuitable.

At room temperature, the formula for choosing \$R\$ is:

$$ R = \frac{0.068}{I} $$

The value shown of \$R=68\Omega\$ will cause 1mA to flow. See page 6 of the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm334.pdf) for more detail.

Your existing design has better compliance voltage range for the LEDs than my design above. However, mirror current will vary with V1:

$$ I_{R1} = \frac{V_1-2V_{BE}}{R_1} $$

By modifying your design slightly, and replacing R1 with an LM334, you can get great compliance voltage range, and constant current all the way down to \$V_1=+1.7V\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzbKWO.png)</sup>

I haven't tested or even simulated any of these ideas, so I suggest you do so, using a good model of the LM334, before you take my word for anything!

If you don't have an LM334 handy, you can roll your own constant current source for the mirror:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgijDF.png)</sup>

Q2 and Q3 are diode connected transistors to obtain a fixed 1.2V potential difference. You could employ regular diodes, but they won't provide such a steady potential difference as V1 changes. There is therefore a more-or-less constant 0.6V across R1, which sets current at about 1mA, down into the mirror.

$$ I = \frac{0.6V}{R_1} $$

Here's current in one of the LEDs as I sweep V1 from 0V to +5V:

[image]

As you can see, LED current changes very little, between 1mA and 1.2mA, and the circuit begins to work from \$V_1=1.7V\$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post all of this good information/data! I will give your suggestions a try.

Answer (score 0):

CMOS GPIOs are already current sources. You'll get best results by not using any series resistors at all, and instead selecting the GPIO drive strength per requirements.

The circuit you show of course will work, but seems unnecessary.